# Bottom align a button Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

is there a helper class that i can use to bottom align the "Search" button below. I am using Boostrap 3.2.

```
<div class="input-group col-md-2">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="FirstName" maxlength="10" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="input-group col-md-2">
  <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="LastName" maxlength="10" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="input-group col-md-2">
  <label for="RecordNo">Record No</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="RecordNo" maxlength="6" name="RecordNo" placeholder="Record No" type="text" value="" />
</div>

<div class="input-group col-md-3">
  <label for="Department">Department</label>
  <select id="Department" class="form-control">
    <option value="">CHOOSE DEPARTMENT</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 input-group">
  <button id="Search" class="btn btn btn-success pull-right">
    Search &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle, please?

Comment: Can you please give a JSFiddle? I guess you are looking for `display:inline`, or `div.inline { float:left; }`

Comment: You're not using `.input-group` the way it's intended. ["Extend form controls by adding text or buttons before, after, or on both sides of any text-based `<input>`. Use `.input-group` with an `.input-group-addon` to prepend or append elements to a single `.form-control`."](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) Your best bet might be to set the containing row's `font-size: 0` and then reset each column's `font-size` to your `@font-size-base`, then set each column to `float:none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .col-lg-4, .col-lg-8     
 { 

float:none;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:-4px;
 }
```

OR use this

```
       .vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
          }
```

Comment: That negative margin is nasty, best to set the row's `font-size: 0;` and then reset the font-size within the columns.

Answer (score 3):

By default, bootstrap column is `position relative`so to position your button just use:

```
button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```